# What is the meaning of "RTM" Version?

Tags: version, licensing

For Example "Visual Studio 2015 `RTM`"

What is feature in this version?

How can use this version?

Comment: Release to Manufacturing. By installing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short for **R**elease **T**o **M**anufacturing,

**RTM versions** are typically released to manufacturers before they are released to the general public so that the manufacturers can work out any bugs the software may encounter with hardware devices.

the version of a software product that is given to manufacturers to bundle into future versions of their hardware products.

The release of an RTM version does not necessarily mean that the creators have worked out all the problems with the software; there still may be more versions of the product before it is released to the general public.